# Passing active Spring profile to AWS ECS Task Container with Command option

Tags: spring, spring-boot, docker, containers, amazon-ecs

I am using AWS CodeBuild to build my Spring Boot application as Docker image and store it in Elastic Container Registry. Following is the excerpt from my Dockerfile

```
#run the app
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-jar","/app.jar"]
```

The build stage is working fine and I get a Docker image created in ECR. I want to use this same Docker image for `staging` and `production` environment. And in order to do that, I have to set the right spring profile when the Docker container is started. I have tried passing the spring profile through `Command` option in ECS Task Container like below but no luck.

> -Dspring.profiles.active=test

> -Dspring.profiles.active,test

> "-Dspring.profiles.active=test"

I know this can be done in `ENTRYPOINT` command but I need to do it dynamically when the container starts. Can anyone guide what is the right way to pass spring profile to ECS Task Container

Answer (score 1):

You should use environments in container definitions for passing spring boot profiles dynamically. You don't require an entry point in the DockerFile.

```
{
"family": "spring-boot-app",
"taskRoleArn": "99895575095",
"containerDefinitions": [
  {
  "image": "%REPOSITORY_URI%",
  "name": "spring-boot-app",
  "cpu": 10,
  "memoryReservation": 300,
  "essential": true,
  "portMappings": [
    {
      "containerPort": 9020,
      "hostPort": 9020
    }
  ],
   "environment": [
     {
      "name": "spring.profiles.active",
      "value": "uat"
    }]
  }]
}
```

You can also parameterize the environment if you are using any shell script or AWS CLI commands but variables with two double quotes as shown below.

```
{"environment":[{"name":"spring.profiles.active","value":"'"$ENVIRONMENT"'"}]}
```

Answer (score 0):

Following is the right command line argument to set the active profile through `Command` option in ECS Task Container

> --spring.profiles.active=test